# Avoiding multiple casts of pointers to structs

Tags: c, struct

I'm wondering if there's a better way to handling pointers to multiple structs, when you use the structs to overlay data you didn't create yourself. I'm trying to parse an ELF file header (the format is well-known, so I won't reproduce the structs here). So, say you have a pointer to a struct for the file header:

`struct elf64_file_hdr *fh;`

One of the fields of the file header is `shoff', which is the offset in bytes from the start of the file to the beginning of section headers, or to be more specific, the beginning of an array of section header structs. So, you can have:

`struct elf64_section_header *sh;`

and access each section header as sh[0], sh[1], etc. The question, then, is how to set `sh' correctly. I've been doing a cast and then recast to make the pointer math work:

`sh = (struct elf64_sec_hdr *)((char *)fh + fh->fh_shoff);`

But it seems like there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: If you have to do this a bunch of times, you could use a macro: `#define GETPTR(_dst,_src,_off) _dst = (__typeof__(_dst)) (((char *) (_src)) + (_off))` and then do: `GETPTR(sh,fh,fh->fh_shoff);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is, beyond wrapping it in a macro. But that doesn't seem too bad. To get around pointer arithmetic you first have to cast away the initial type, then you need to cast the result to the type you want. That's exactly what you're doing.

Here's a macro to do it, casting the result to `void*` so it will automatically convert to the right type.

```
#define AT_OFFSET(base, offset) ((void*)((char*)(base) + (offset)))
...
struct elf64_sec_hdr *sh = AT_OFFSET(fh, fh->fh_shoff);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I only need to do the ELF header cast once, but a macro would help elsewhere, like parsing ACPI tables that hold absolute addresses with a high-memory-mapped kernel.